# Why this is not showing the email on the form?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to get the user email to automatically fit the form whenever the button is clicked (ideally when the page loads), but it is not working as it should. I am working on Google Apps Script.

Code.gs

```
function doGet(){
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");} 

function email(){
var correo = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
}
```

page.html

```
<html> 
<body> 
<label>Name:</label> <input type="text" id="username">
<button id="btn"> Run it!</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",correousuario);
function(){
google.script.run.email();
document.getElementById("username").value = correo;
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is no function named `correousuario` in your code.

gs:

```
function doGet(){
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");} 

//added return to this function
function email(){return Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();}
```

page.html

```
<html> 
<body> 
<label>Name:</label> <input type="text" id="username">
<button id="btn"> Run it!</button>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  //its generally better to wait for all of the elements to get loaded before adding listeners
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",correousuario);      
}

function correousuario(){
google.script.run
withSuccessHandler(function(e){
  document.getElementById("username").value = e;
})
.email();
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thi solved the issue.